# Starting only one service from a compose file with DockerComposeContainer

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, testcontainers

Is that possible somehow to run only specific services in a Testcontainers `DockerComposeContainer`?

Using the example in [the official documentation](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java), could we start only Redis?  For me all the services start all the time (and it doesn't matter whether have I used the `withExposedService` method or not).

I mean a method like this:

```java
new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/compose-test.yml"))
        .composeUpService("redis_1")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code of [DockerComposeContainer](http://testcontainers-java/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.java), it appears the answer is no, but only because [`DockerComposeContainer.runWithCompose`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/834b19f2df704c0a8ceb657d663ca7bbc4c6e002/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.java#L212) is private.

From the usage of that method in other places such as [`DockerComposeContainer.createServices`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/834b19f2df704c0a8ceb657d663ca7bbc4c6e002/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.java#L175) it seems all that would be needed is to expose `runWithCompose` and you could have the full docker-compose command set, allowing something like:

```
new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/compose-test.yml"))
      .runWithCompose("run -d redis");
```

(and other [`docker-compose run` options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)).

It's a pretty active project in github, so you may get traction on this with an issue submission or better yet a pull request.

Comment: As a workaround, you could create a separate docker-compose file that just has the one service you want.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to start a subset of the servers was added to Testcontainers 1.11.4 via the addition of the [`withServices(String... services)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.13.0/org/testcontainers/containers/DockerComposeContainer.html#withServices-java.lang.String...-) method ([#1497](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1497)).  However, this feature was accidentally broken in 1.12.4 and is still broken in the latest 1.13.0 release ([#2191](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2191)).

In a version of the library that works, you can therefore do the following to start up just the single Redis service:

```java
new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/compose-test.yml"))
    .withServices("redis_1")
```